# create zero electromagnetic field area

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to understand electromagnetic fields so I have two question related to them.

What is a zero electromagnetic field area? Does it related to zero point energy?

Comment: No connection, afaik, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy I have heard of, but I am guessing a zero e/m field  area is pretty much what it says it is.  Could be wrong though.

Comment: It sounds like something that a municipality would establish: no wifi, etc.

Comment: @Pieter  You could be on to something, A pub owner in the UK has finally snapped, wants his customers to talk face to face [Installing a Faraday Cage to encourage conversation](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-sussex-36943686)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A region with zero electromagnetic field can have no photons in it - as photons are really just electromagnetic radiation. Now since all matter that has temperature emits black body radiation (photons), such a region would have to be perfectly evacuated (no atoms allowed), and surrounded by walls that are at zero K temperature. These walls would also have to be perfect conductors to shield against electromagnetic radiation from "outside". And perfectly thick - a penetrating cosmic gamma ray would again create electromagnetic radiation.

I struggle to see how such a region can exist, and how it might relate to zero point energy. I suppose that when the walls are at absolute zero, the atoms making up the wall still have ZPE- but for me the analogy ends there.

It is possible I am missing something much deeper.